# Why is my Twig Override not displaying any content, when the original Twig was barely different and worked just fine?

Tags: theming

I'm overriding a Twig template for the responsive_menu module, and encountering an issue with content not displaying.

The original Twig is named `responsive-menu-horizontal.html.twig` and my replacement is named `block--responsive-menu-horizontal-menu.html.twig`. Please note that the name of the replacement was derived from my Inspect Element debugger's suggestions.

The two Twig pages are almost exactly the same, save for the names and the added classes for the ul and li pieces

![1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T25DZ.png

When I use my override for the default Twig page, the nav completely disappears, and my debugger leaves me with this:

```
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'themes/indyres/templates/block/block--responsive-menu-horizontal-menu.html.twig' -->
<!-- END OUTPUT from 'themes/indyres/templates/block/block--responsive-menu-horizontal-menu.html.twig' -->
```

I'm confounded as to how it'll read my overriding template and render *nothing*. Any help/explanation is greatly appreciated, this is the first Drupal project I've ever worked on, and though I managed to keep my head above water in creating the styles for the rest of the site, this piece has me really lost.

Comment: Block templates are different than menu templates.

Comment: That's what I thought, but my debugger, and even the previous template that was working, is under the block.html.twig. I tried changing it from block-- to menu-- and it just reverted to the previous template.

Comment: Ok, so the question is a bit confusing, but so is the responsive_menu module. The responsive_menu module implements a block plugin, which allows you to place things around. All blocks have a basic template like you see above `block--responsive-menu-horizontal-menu.html.twig`, but the responsive_menu module also implements additional template, theme wrappers in its render array (the PHP content that gets sent to the theme layer). So `responsive-menu-horizontal.html.twig` is a different template than your block. So the template replacement file name is incorrect for what you want to override.

Comment: I probably can't make that an answer without additional details in the question about what you're trying to override exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of frustration, and realizing that I could (in fact) manage to get Superfish to do what I had originally wanted, I just `composer remove`'d the module and that's where it'll stay. Thanks for the help everybody!